# launching a script at ubuntu start up

Tags: startup-applications

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a virtual machine and I'm trying to set it up so that when it starts up it also automatically follow the description on the `startmeup.sh.desktop` to start the script `taskhome.sh`.

The `startmeup.sh.desktop` script has the following code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/kvm/scripts/taskhome.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en]=Startmeup
Name=Startmeup
Comment[en]=
Comment=
```

I put the file `startmeup.sh.desktop` on the folder `config\autostart` and I made it executable with the `chmod +x` command, but when I reboot Ubuntu the script `taskhome.sh` is not executed (I guess it's just because the `startmeup.sh.desktop` is simply not executed either).

If I launch the `taskhome.sh` script manually I don't have any problem.
    If I open the folder that contains the script startmeup.sh.desktop, and I double click on it, the `taskhome.sh` script starts without any problem.

However if I try to execute the `startmeup.sh.desktop` script on a terminal with the command `./startmeup.sh.desktop` then I get the error "

```
line 1: [Desktop: command not found.
```

Is there something I can do to make the script work on Ubuntu start up?

Comment: Running the .desktop file itself in a terminal doesn't work (even if it's executable). What's the script supposed to do? It's not set to run in a terminal, so could be running already & you don't see it.

Comment: @Marest Copy your .desktop file to `cp /path/to/startmeup.sh.desktop ~/.config/autostart/` and then try `chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/startmeup.sh.desktop`. will work.

Comment: @KasiyA why making a .desktop file executable? .desktop files are configuration files, not "scripts", so making it executable is just a wast of time (and a potential security issue).

Comment: @Braiam Yes, you are right.

Comment: In Thunar (XFCE) executing a .desktop file *without* it being executable (even in `~/.config/autostart`) says "Untrusted application launcher - The desktop file "xxx.desktop" is in an insecure location and not marked as executable. If you do not trust this program, click Cancel." Making it executable then shows it's name using the "Name=" tag, and not it's filename.

Comment: FYI to anyone else reading, @Marest replied with an "Answer" saying they *had the script in the wrong folder.* (If they come back they could select an answer)

Answer (score 3):

Running `./startmeup.sh.desktop` from the terminal will not work, as the `.desktop` is not a shell script.

Also add:

```
Terminal=true
```

that might be of help!

To start application on startup, you need to do it the usual way:

- [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/36315)

Answer (score 2):

Wait a minute, what folder did you put the script in? Your Q says `config\autostart`... it's supposed to be in `~/.config/autostart` (in your home folder) and should run when the user logs in, not only on bootup (unless that user is automatically logged in too)

You don't have an `Icon=...` line, but that might not bake a big difference.

And what's the script supposed to do? It's not set to run in a terminal (`Terminal=true` might do that) so how do you know it's not running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Exec=" mode with this one:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x /home/kvm/scripts/taskhome.sh
```

Manpage for -x:

```
-x, --execute
Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal.
```

Should be like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -x /home/kvm/scripts/taskhome.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en]=Startmeup
Name=Startmeup
```